# Select checkboxes that match some conditions by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, coffeescript

In my html I have some checkboxes. When i want to find every checkboxes by jquery i do something like this:

```
 $("#car_additions tr td input[type=\"checkbox\"]")
```

and this gives me the following output in Firebug:

```
Object[input#car_car_addition_assignments_attributes_0_car_addition_id.boolean wartość atrybutu = "11", input#car_car_addition_assignments_attributes_0_default.boolean wartość atrybutu = "1", input#car_car_addition_assignments_attributes_3_car_addition_id.boolean wartość atrybutu = "12", input#car_car_addition_assignments_attributes_3_default.boolean wartość atrybutu = "1"]
```

Now I want to find only checkboxes that id ends like:

```
car_addition_id.boolean
```

Is there any way to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) available in jQuery :

```
$('#car_additions tr td input[type="checkbox"][id$="car_addition_id.boolean"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) for that.

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.

**Code:**

```
 $( "input[id$='car_addition_id.boolean']" )
```